# Git repo with files from multiple directories (dotfiles syncing)

Tags: git, dotfiles

I would like to create a repo with my dotfiles and some other files I would like to sync across multiple machines. The files are spread across several directories (not only `~` home directory).

Can git keep track of files from several directories that are not necessarily subdirectories to where `.git/` is stored?

The best solutions I've come up right now is to make a script to copy dotfiles into single directory where git repo has been init.

Answer (score 2):

What people normally do is have a git repo somewhere, say `~/.dotfiles` and then use symbolic links from that directory to where the dot file should be.

See [dotfiles on Github](https://dotfiles.github.io/) for more inspiration.